# Every Cauchy sequence in a metric space $(X,d)$ is bounded.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification

MY attempt: Suppose $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $(X,d)$. Take $\varepsilon = 1 $. Hence, can find $N$ such that $d(x_m,x_n) < 1 $ for all $n,m >  N$.

Also, we have $d(x_N, x_n) < 1 $ for all $n > N$. Hence,

$$ d(a,x_n) \leq d(a, x_N) + d(x_N,x_n) < d(a,x_N) + 1.$$

Put $K = \max \{ d(a,x_i) : 1 \leq i < N \} $

$$\therefore d(a,x_n) \leq K \; \; \forall n > N$$

So $(x_n)$ is bounded. Is this a correct approach?

Also, is boundedness of a sequence sufficient for the sequence to be cauchy? convergent?

My answer is not. For instance, $x_n = (-1)^n$ is bounded, but it is not Cauchy, neither convergent. IS this correct?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks all good to me.

Comment: The approach is right, but there are a few mistakes. You need a couple of weak inequalities where you have strict ones, and for $n > N$, you can only deduce $d(a,x_n) < K+1$. Your counterexample to the second question is spot-on.

Comment: Everything looks great. If you further want a Cauchy sequence which is not convergent (to prove that all the implications "convergent $\Rightarrow$ Cauchy $\Rightarrow$ bounded" are not reversible), you need to take a sequence in a non-complete space, for instance, the sequence of $(1+1/n)^n$ is a Cauchy sequence in the metric space $\mathbb Q$ but does not converge (because it converges in $\mathbb R$ to the irrationnal number $e$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach looks good to me. Also, an sequence can be Cauchy but not necessary to be convergence. For instance, you can consider an in-complete space for start because in complete space cauchy is equal to convergent.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is absolutely correct.

Your counter-example, i.e., $x_n=(-1)^n$, is also correct.