# Show that the metric space $(\overline{\mathbb{R}},d)$ is complete, if $d(x,y):=|\arctan x-\arctan y|$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces, solution-verification

Consider the space $\mathbb{R}$ equipped with the distance function $$d(x,y):=|\arctan x-\arctan y|.$$ There are several posts to prove that $(\mathbb{R},d)$ is not complete. For instance, [Real numbers equipped with the metric $ d (x,y) = | \arctan(x) - \arctan(y)| $ is an incomplete metric space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/152243/real-numbers-equipped-with-the-metric-d-x-y-arctanx-arctany-i?rq=1)
and
[Show that $(\mathbb{R},d)$ is not complete , where $d(x,y) =|\arctan(x) - \arctan(y)|$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3101549/show-that-mathbbr-d-is-not-complete-where-dx-y-arctanx-arcta?noredirect=1&lq=1)

From these posts, I saw that the problematic term is $\pm\infty$, so I think perhaps we can complete this metric space by simply adding $\pm\infty$.

That is, if denote $\overline{\mathbb{R}}:=[-\infty,\infty]$, I want to show that $(\overline{\mathbb{R}},d)$ is complete. To this end, I need to show every Cauchy sequence in this space with respect to the metric $d$ converges in $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$.

I tried to separate the case into bounded Cauchy sequence and unbounded Cauchy sequence, but I did not see how to show the convergence is in the space.

For example, let $(x_{n})$ be a Cauchy sequence in $(\overline{\mathbb{R}},d)$. Suppose it is bounded, that is $|x_{n}|\leq M$ for all $n$ and for some constant $M$. But then what should I do?

For unbounded sequence, then $x_{n}\nearrow\infty$ directly and $\infty$ has been included in $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$, so we are done in this case, right?

For the boundedness here, I mean a Cauchy sequence with respect to the arctan metric but is bounded/unbounded in the usual absolute value metric.

Thanks for any help!

---

**Edit 1:**

As suggested by the comment, I need to define $$d(-\infty,\infty):=|-\dfrac{\pi}{2}-\dfrac{\pi}{2}|=\pi,\ \ \ d(x,\infty):=|\arctan x-\dfrac{\pi}{2}|,\ \ \ d(-\infty, x):=|-\dfrac{\pi}{2}-\arctan x|.$$

But then what I should do?

---

**Edit 2: A possible solution:**

Okay, I think I solved it using isometry. I am not sure if I am correct, so I added a tag of proof verification. The followings are the complete proof:

Denote $\overline{\mathbb{R}}:=[-\infty,\infty]$. We firstly need to extend the definition of $d(x,y)$ such that it is defined on such a space. That is, we further define
$$d(x,y):=\left\{
  \begin{array}{ll}
  |\arctan(x)-\arctan(y)|\ \ \text{if}\ \ x,y\in\mathbb{R}\\
  \frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan (y)\ \ \text{if}\ \ x=\infty\ \ \text{and}\ \ y\in\mathbb{R}\\
  \frac{\pi}{2}+\arctan (y)\ \ \text{if}\ \ x=-\infty\ \ \text{and}\ \ y\in\mathbb{R}\\
  \pi\ \ \text{if}\ \ x=-\infty\ \ \text{and}\ \ y=\infty.
  \end{array}
\right.
$$
As $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\arctan(x)=\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty}\arctan(x)=-\frac{\pi}{2}$, the above extended definition is clearly well-defined.

We now prove that $(\overline{\mathbb{R}},d)$ is complete. To this end, we define $f:\overline{\mathbb{R}}\longrightarrow [-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$ by
$$f(x):=\left\{
  \begin{array}{ll}
  \arctan(x)\ \ \text{if}\ \ x\in\mathbb{R}\\
  \frac{\pi}{2}\ \ \text{if}\ \ x=\infty\\
  -\frac{\pi}{2}\ \ \text{if}\ \ x=-\infty.
  \end{array}
\right.
$$
Then, defining $d'(x,y):=|x-y|$, we see that for any $a,b\in \overline{\mathbb{R}}$, we have $$d'(f(a),f(b))=d(a,b).$$

Therefore, we see that $(\overline{\mathbb{R}},d)$ and $([-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}],d')$ are isometric. Hence, it follows from general topology that $(\overline{\mathbb{R}},d)$ is complete if and only if $([-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}],d')$ is complete.

But note that $[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$ is compact with respect to the usual metric $d'$, and we recall from general topology that every compact metric space is complete. Hence, $([-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}],d')$ is complete.

The proof is then concluded.

Please let me know if I am correct!

Comment: Have you checked that d still defines a metric on this space? I.e. that distances to the symbols $\pm \infty$ are well-defined?

Comment: What I mean is that $x_n\to \infty$ means that $d(x_n, \infty)<\epsilon$ but can you make sense of the Lufthansa side? Because if you interpret the symbol $\infty$ as greater than all numbers, there probably is no „convergence to $\infty$“.

Comment: In order to add $\infty$ and $-\infty$, you will have to define both $d(-\infty,\infty)$, and $d(x,\infty)$ and $d(x,-\infty)$ for each $x\in\Bbb R$.

Comment: What do you mean by *unbounded* Cauchy sequence? A Cauchy sequence is always bounded. See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/662557/every-cauchy-sequence-in-a-metric-space-x-d-is-bounded).

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I guess I will just define $d(-\infty,\infty)=|-\dfrac{\pi}{2}-\dfrac{\pi}{2}|=\pi$, $d(x,\infty)=|x-\dfrac{\pi}{2}|$ and $d(x,-\infty)=|x+\dfrac{\pi}{2}|$. I am not sure if this works.

Comment: @azif00 well.... you are right... so...do you know what I should do instead?

Comment: @JacobsonRadical: Not quite: you want to replace $x$ by $\tan^{-1}x$ in the last two definitions.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott yeah, right. Sorry about that.

Comment: @sampleuser yeah, you are right. I just edited the post.

Comment: @azif00 a second thought. I mean a Cauchy sequence with respect to the arctan metric but is unbounded in the usual absolute value metric.

Comment: Your proof looks fine to me. Still I want to give a little warning: this solves the problem of sequences like $\frac \pi 2-\frac 1n$ not having limits in $(-\frac \pi 2, \frac \pi 2)$. But for the equivalent point $\infty -\frac 1n$ you have the problem that it is not clear what this is supposed to mean without further explanation. That is, what point of $\overline{\mathbb R}$ is $\infty-\frac 1n$?

Comment: @sampleuser okay... do you have some suggestions for refinement? I am a little bit confused..

Comment: I think you should bear in mind that you are working here with an abstract symbol and that there are some details hiding in the back, eg the arithmetic on $\overline{\mathbb R}$. I briefly checked https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line and think it contains all you need so you might want to check it out to see all the background definitions you need when working with a two point compactification and abstract symbols (personably, I prefer to look at $\infty$ as being a symbol instead of something arbitrarily large but that’s a topologists point of view).

Comment: Just as an aside: there are minor pints in your notation that should be fixed. It is not $f(x)\colon \overline{\mathbb R}\to \dots$ but $f\colon\dots$. Use $f(x)$ only for saying how a point x is mapped and not for the entire function. Also you sometimes write the metric space first and sometimes the metric first ($(M, d)$ v. $(d, M)$). You should stick to one notation.

Comment: @sampleuser Thank you so much for such a detailed suggestion and recommendation! :)

Comment: Why not use the fact that $[-\tfrac\pi 2,\tfrac\pi 2]$ with the standard metric is complete and note that your metric on $[-\infty,\infty]$ is obtained by [transporting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_of_structure) the standard metric along the bijection $[-\infty,\infty]\to[-\tfrac\pi 2,\tfrac\pi 2]$ given by $x\mapsto \arctan(x)$?

Comment: @Christoph I guess what you suggested is in my edit.

Comment: @JacobsonRadical Right, your "Edit 2" is exactly that!

Comment: @Christoph nice. Thanks for your confirmation :)) I do need it.